# Xcode Interface Builder - Make compound map multiscreen compatible

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Got a map which is composed of multiple parts:

[image]

Each part is an `UIButton` with an Image. I positioned everything to make up the map and it first looks all right. The problem I have is about resizing the `View` for different screens sizes. Tried with Autoresizing and Constraints but couldn't get it to look properly for minimizing and maximizing it. The parts should always sick together and up-/downscale according to the screen size. I'm testing the behaviour directly in the Interface Builder by resizing xib's dimensions.

What works is setting all arrows in autoresizingMask for each `UIButton` and maximizing the view. But minimizing it distorts the map.

Unfortunately it's the first time for me working with the Interface Builder in Xcode. Here you find the [source files](https://github.com/xamadev/CustomRendererUIView/tree/master/CustomRendererUIView/CustomRendererUIView.iOS/Views/Compound%20map%20problem). Thanks!

**Edit:**
Setting only the arrows for width and height in the autoresizingMask makes it possible to downscale without distortion. Upscaling pulls the parts apart. How to support proper up-/downscaling simultaneously?

**Edit1:**
Replaced the every `UIButton` with `UIImage` which resize properly in the Interface Builder! See [repo here](https://github.com/xamadev/iOS-Compound-Map). Unfortunately on simualtor devices the Autoresizing differs and the map-parts don't stick together anymore. Setting the size of UIView in Main.storyboard exactly to xib's size the Autoresizing works perfectly (tested on multiple devices). But later on in the "real" project I'm not in control over the parent's view dimensions.
Played a litte bit with [this line of code](https://github.com/xamadev/iOS-Compound-Map/blob/master/TestXIB/CustomView.swift#L10) and it seems to be responsible for "blocking" Autoresizing. How to avoid that? Thanks in advance. I think I’m maybe mixing up Autoresizing with AspectFit which seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be much easier if all the Bundesländer images had the same size. Put them all on top of each other in a common view. Give all the buttons zero padding to all side. Subclass UIButton to check if the the touch event is on a non transparent pixel. Search for "irregular button ios" to find out more about it.

---

I am able to achieve this using this images, which have all the same size, border added to demonstrate size

[image: NDS]
[image: NRW]
[image: Hessen]
[image: Sachsen-Anhalt]

and this constraints

[image: the constraints iPhone]
[image: the constraints iPad]

The most important constraint might be the Aspect Ratio Constraint on MapWrapper, the view that contains all the buttons.

---

Using Ole Begemann's [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)
[image: OBShapedButton]

---

Some notes:

- Your image content is perfect for factorised graphics. Export them to pdf and add them as such as single scale to your assets
- you should not include the states names' in the images, but use it as the buttons titles'. To position them correctly, use title insets.

---

example project: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/germanStateSelection

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vikingosegundo. Could you please share your project? I made progress using UIImageViews instead of UIButtons (have a look at Edit1 please).
>>Subclass UIButton to check if the the touch event is on a non transparent pixel
That's a good point. [This](https://github.com/xamadev/iOS-Shaped-Button-Swift) works with UIButton. I'll test it with UIImageView, so far there's at least no syntax error. Guess it should work also.

Comment: I added an example project

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Resizing works fine. But the problem I have with your solution is that the MapWrapper isn't outsourced to an extra xib file. Doing this doesn't allow me to set constraints. Is there a way using only Autoresizing mask and Content Mode Aspect Fit in the xib file and let it up/downscale proportionally in the displaying parentview?

Comment: not sure what issues you saw for xibs, but I hacked a version together that works with those.

Comment: Seriously: i have answered your question sufficiently. Doing so I invested quite some time. If new questions arose, feel free to answer a new follow up question — after thorough research of course.